# How to find log4shell vulnerable classes in my assemblies (jar/ear/war)

Tags: java, security, log4j, log4shell

Around the current log4shell situation i need a way to find out if i have vulnerable classes in my packaged products.
What is the easiest way to find if the following classes are contained in jar files packaged in EAR or WAR files?

- JndiLookup.class
- JMSAppenderBase.class
- JMSAppender.class

Comment: For .ear and .war files it’s easy:  `jar tf MyApplication.ear | grep log4j` (Unix) or `jar tf MyApplication.ear | findstr "log4j"` (Windows).  Of course, you also need to extract and check every .war file inside an .ear file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be the following bat script:

```
@echo off
echo extraction step 1
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -r -aos -bd -otmp *
echo creating filelist
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l -r -aos -bd tmp/* >filelist.txt
echo cleanup
rmdir /s /q tmp
echo analysis result:
find "JndiLookup.class" filelist.txt
find "JMSAppenderBase.class" filelist.txt
find "JMSAppender.class" filelist.txt
pause
```